# Can we send multiple data in a single metric using aws cloudwatch cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Is there a way to send multiple data in a single metric using aws cloudwatch cli.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried specifying a json object and putting multiple items within that list?

i.e.

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace "Usage Metrics" --metric-data file://metric.json
```

Where metric.json is something like:

```
[
{
"MetricName": "Metric1",
"Timestamp": "Wednesday, November 2, 2013 8:28:20 AM",
"Value": 0.50,
"Unit": "Count"
}, 
{
"MetricName": Metric2,
"Timestamp": "Wednesday, November 2, 2013 8:28:20 AM",
"Value": 1,
"Unit": "Count"
}, 

{
"MetricName": "Metric 2",
"Timestamp": "Wednesday, November 2, 2013 8:29:20 AM",
"Value": 5,
"Unit": "Count"
}
]
```

if you need to send multiple values for one metric, something like:

```
[
{
"MetricName": "Metric1",
"Timestamp": "Wednesday, November 2, 2013 8:28:20 AM",
"Values": [0.50,2,3,5.1],
"Unit": "Count"
} 
]
```

or

```
[
    {
    "MetricName": "Metric1",
    "Timestamp": "Wednesday, November 2, 2013 8:28:20 AM",
    "StatisticValues": {
       "SampleCount": 8,
       "Sum": 18,
       "Minimum": 2.3,
       "Maximum": 2.7
    },
    "Unit": "None"
    } 
]
```

Comment: I think you need one Metric with two dimensions and values for each dimension, but it's unclear what you're trying to do and the requirements keep changing.